# How can I make uploadArchives dependent on another task?

Tags: java, android, maven, deployment, gradle

I have the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
  uploadArchives {
    repositories {
      mavenDeployer {
        configuration = configurations.deployerJars
        pom.packaging = "aar"
        pom.groupId = project.CORE_GROUP
        pom.version = project.CORE_VERSION_NAME

        repository(url: "scp://" + project.CORE_MAVEN_URL) {
          authentication(userName: project.uploadUsername, privateKey: project.uploadKeyFile)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want it to be dependent on the following task:

```
task checkProperties << {
  if (!project.hasProperty('uploadUsername')) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find uploadUsername property. Did you forget to specify it in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties?")
  } else if (!project.hasProperty('uploadKeyFile')) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find uploadKeyFile property. Did you forget to specify it in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties?")
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this? If I write the following:

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
  uploadArchives(dependsOn: checkProperties) {
    repositories {
      mavenDeployer {
        configuration = configurations.deployerJars
        pom.packaging = "aar"
        pom.groupId = project.CORE_GROUP
        pom.version = project.CORE_VERSION_NAME

        repository(url: "scp://" + project.CORE_MAVEN_URL) {
          authentication(userName: project.uploadUsername, privateKey: project.uploadKeyFile)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/scottjohnson/Source/core-android/core/build.gradle' line: 61

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':core'.
> org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method mavenDeployer() for arguments [build_42edqo477lbj5geoh0e3gdkj7q$_run_closure6_closure9_closure10_closure11@30b8afce] on repository container.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.68 secs
```

BTW, the reason I want to do this is that right now, if I just put the code that checks the properties into the `uploadArchives` task, then even if I run `./gradlew clean build`, it checks the properties (which I don't want to happen on my build server, since it doesn't have permission to actually upload the archives). Thus, a method that would check the properties only when the `uploadArchives` task is executed would also be acceptable.

Comment: Why You invoke `UploadArchives` right after `projectEvaluate` is fired? Shouldn't it be independent task?

Comment: @Opal I do that because if I don't enclose it in that closure, then I get an undefined property exception: `> Could not find property 'uploadUsername' on project ':core'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out based in part on @Opal's comment:

```
def checkProperties() {                                                         
  if (!project.hasProperty('uploadUsername')) {                                 
   throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find uploadUsername property. Did you forget to specify it in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties?")
  } else if (!project.hasProperty('uploadKeyFile')) {                           
    throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find uploadKeyFile property. Did you forget to specify it in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties?")
  }                                                                             
}                                                                               

uploadArchives {                                                                
  repositories {                                                                
    mavenDeployer {                                                             
      configuration = configurations.deployerJars                               
      pom.packaging = "aar"                                                     
      pom.groupId = project.CORE_GROUP                                          
      pom.version = project.CORE_VERSION_NAME                                   
      repository(url: "scp://" + project.CORE_MAVEN_URL) {                      
      }                                                                         
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
}                                                                               

// We need to check to make sure the properties are available before we execute 
// uploadArchives.                                                              
gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task aTask ->                                     
  if (aTask == uploadArchives) {                                                
    checkProperties()                                                           
    aTask.repositories.mavenDeployer.repository(url: "scp://" + project.CORE_MAVEN_URL) {
      authentication(userName: project.uploadUsername, privateKey: project.uploadKeyFile)
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
}
```

Comment: So, apparently this isn't working as well as I thought... it still gives me an error if I try to run `./gradlew clean build` - that is, even if `uploadArchives` isn't being run, it checks for the properties.

Comment: It will because the whole code is run at the configuration phase of build. Not execution.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding to your error message you might miss to apply the maven plugin to your build.gradle file (apply plugin: 'maven').

See: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/configure-mavendeployer-programmatically/16956/2

Answer (score 2):

Maybe You can try something like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def uploadUsername = project.hasProperty('uploadUsername') ? project['uploadUsername'] : ''
def uploadKeyFile = project.hasProperty('uploadKeyFile') ? project['uploadKeyFile'] : ''

uploadArchives { }

task checkProperties << {
   if (!uploadUsername) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find uploadUsername property. Did you forget to specify it in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties?")
   } else if (!uploadKeyFile) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find uploadKeyFile property. Did you forget to specify it in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties?")
   }
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn(checkProperties)
```

At the beginning both properties are read and assigned to two variables. If any of them not exists, simple empty value will be assigned. It doesn't interfere with build flow. Then `uploadArchives` is declared to depend on `checkProperties`. If it's invoked `checkProperties` will be run and throw exception if any of declared variables is empty.

Comment: I get an exception if I add `(dependsOn: checkProperties)` to the end of the `uploadArchives` task.

Comment: So, this still isn't quite right because `checkProperties` will still be run during evaluation (i.e. when I run `./gradlew clean build` and I don't have the variables defined, it throws the exception. I edited my own answer above to indicate a method that worked for me.

Comment: That's not possible. `checkProperties` will be run during build not during configuration phase. Updated answer once again, with working sample.

Comment: I've been able to get a slightly modified version the updated version of this answer (10/13/14 edit) to work for me on a similar problem. What changes I had to make were tailoring to the specifics of my problem, not the solution's general form.

Comment: If checkProperties causes an error during "gradlew clean build", my first guess would be that it omitted shortcut operator (<<) seen in the 10/13/14 edits (possibly earlier--I only saw 10/13/14 content)

The same code with the shortcut operator omitted is still a valid gradle build file with crucially different semantics.

With "<<" operator, block execution is conditional, depending on whether or not "checkProperties" is in task dependency graph, as desired.

Without "<<" operator, block becomes an unconditional initialization block for "checkProperties" task.